# Does google voice require a data plan to place calls?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, data-connection, google-voice

I own a Nexus S and will be travelling to US on a business trip. I will have a T-Mobile prepaid connection and intend to use Google Voice to make and receive calls.

Since I am currently outside the US, I cannot determine whether GV android app requires a cellular data plan to make calls.

Comment: You can call your Google Voice number from one of your forwarding phones and then enter the phone # you want to call, if you want to avoid data use entirely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little bit yes. (See comments below) The app will make this seamless but should still use a bit of data.

Edit: After checking Google Help I found this:

> By calling your own Google number
>
> When you call your own Google number
>   and sign into the Google voicemail
>   system, you’ll have the option to
>   place a call. Just press 2 and enter
>   the number.
>
> For calls within the U.S, enter area
>   code and number. For example:
>   212-555-2222. For international calls,
>   enter 011, the country code, and the
>   number (or "1 and the country code,"
>   depending on where you're calling).
>   For example: 011442012345612345 or
>   12464260200

Comment: Neat, I was wondering about this myself. I figured (wrongly) that the app dialed Google for you first.

Comment: Is it possible to have GV dial google and then place the call? This way I would only need an unlimited voice plan without data.

Comment: See edit, best way to see if I was a bit wrong with the Android app is, on your smart phone (2.2 or higher) turn off data packets and wifi. If you can still make a call with your Google voice number. The android app makes the calling using what is in my edit above

Comment: Correction: The GV app doesn't have Google call your phone. It actually calls a special number that gets hooked up to your destination number automatically. It then messes with the call logs to make it show the destination number instead of the middleman. It requires a data plan to get this special middleman number to call, but it caches it afterwards.